# Extract sub-periods within a period

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, intervals

Given a period starting from `StartingDate` to `EndingDate`.
I want to get the intervals within that period starting given `StartingMonth` and `EndingMonth`.

Example :

```
StartingMonth = april (4) 
EndingMonth = november (11)
```

Periods :

```
Period A : StartingDate =  (2014, 03, 01); EndingDate = (2015, 02, 28);
Period B : StartingDate =  (2014, 07, 01); EndingDate = (2015, 06, 30);
Period C : StartingDate =  (2014, 01, 01); EndingDate = (2015, 12, 31);
```

Would return :

```
Period A : 1 sub-period = (2014, 4, 1) - (2014, 11, 30)
Period B : 2 sub-periods = (2014, 7, 1) - (2014, 11, 30) ; (2015, 4, 1) - (2015, 6, 30)
Period C : 2 sub-periods = (2014, 4, 1) - (2014, 11, 30) ; (2015, 4, 1) - (2015, 11, 30)
```

I have tried this (seems to be the hard way and does not manage multiple sub-periods): 
May be an easier way using LINQ ?

```
if (StartingDate.Month < startingMonth && EndingDate.Month < endingMonth)
{
    periods.Add(new PeriodInterval
    {
        StartDate = new DateTime(StartingDate.Year, startingMonth, 1), 
        EndDate = new DateTime(StartingDate.Year, endingMonth, EndingDate.Day)
    });
}

if (StartingDate.Month > startingMonth && EndingDate.Month > endingMonth)
{
     periods.Add(new PeriodInterval
    {
       StartDate = new DateTime(StartingDate.Year, startingMonth, 1), 
       EndDate = new DateTime(StartingDate.Year, endingMonth, EndingDate.Day)
     });
}

if (StartingDate.Month < startingMonth && EndingDate.Month > endingMonth)
{
    periods.Add(new PeriodInterval
    {
        StartDate = new DateTime(StartingDate.Year, startingMonth, 1), 
        EndDate = new DateTime(StartingDate.Year, endingMonth, EndingDate.Day)
    });                   
}

if (StartingDate.Month > startingMonth && EndingDate.Month < endingMonth)
{
    periods.Add(new PeriodInterval
    {
        StartDate = new DateTime(StartingDate.Year, startingMonth, 1), 
        EndDate = new DateTime(StartingDate.Year, endingMonth, EndingDate.Day)
    });                    
}
```

The idea is to returns the blue periods within the red period : 
   [image: The idea is to returns the blue periods within the red period]

Comment: Is there some set rules for what constitutes a 'period'? Or is that a class that can be created dynamically? If the second question is true, is there a need to have these 'periods' repeat for every year?

Comment: No. The `PeriodInterval` class can be modified or created dynamically.

Comment: Ok, maybe give me some background on the real world purpose for this? I'm not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Suppose we offer you a discount from april to november. this discount will be valid for 4 year. I Have to extract **periods** where the discount is applied.

Comment: 4/2014 to 11/2014 I can get the discount, and then if I get it, it will be valid for 4 years? Meaning I can come back and get the discount from 4/2014 to 4/2018?

Comment: The word 'period' has no meaning to me. It could mean 2 weeks, 8 weeks, 1 year.

Comment: A **period** is an instance of `PeriodInterval`. Starting at date d1 and ending at date d2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57033/discussion-between-michael-b-and-hdoghmen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Discount
{
    public int DiscountID { get; set; } //You will need some Key field if you are storing these in a database.
    public DateTime issueDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime expirationDate { get; set; }

    public List<PeriodInterval> intervals { get; set; }

    public Discount(DateTime IssueDate, DateTime ExpirationDate)
    {
        issueDate = IssueDate;
        expirationDate = ExpirationDate;
        intervals = new List<PeriodInterval>();
    }

    public void AddInterval(DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate)
    {
        intervals.Add(new PeriodInterval() { 
            StartMonth=StartDate.Month,
            StartDay=StartDate.Day,
            EndMonth=EndDate.Month,
            EndDay=EndDate.Day
        });
    }
    public List<Period> GetPeriods()
    {
        List<Period> periods=new List<Period>();
        int yearCount = expirationDate.Year-issueDate.Year+1; //+1: Run at least one year against the periods.
        for (int i = 0; i < yearCount; i++)
        {
            //Loop through all the years and add 'Periods' from all the PeriodInterval info.
            foreach (PeriodInterval pi in intervals)
            {
                var period = pi.GetPeriod(issueDate, expirationDate, i);
                if (period != null)
                    periods.Add(period);
            }
        }
        return periods;
    }
}
class Period
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
class PeriodInterval
{
    public int PeriodIntervalID { get; set; } //You will need some Key field if you are storing these in a database.
    public int DiscountID { get; set; } //Foreign Key to Discount. This is alsof for database storage.

    public int StartMonth { get; set; }
    public int StartDay { get; set; }

    public int EndMonth { get; set; }
    public int EndDay { get; set; }

    public Period GetPeriod(DateTime issueDate, DateTime expirationDate, int Year)
    {
        DateTime PeriodStart = new DateTime(issueDate.AddYears(Year).Year, StartMonth, StartDay);
        DateTime PeriodEnd = new DateTime(issueDate.AddYears(Year).Year, EndMonth, EndDay);

        PeriodStart=new DateTime(Math.Max(PeriodStart.Ticks, issueDate.Ticks)); //Limit period to the max of the two start dates.
        PeriodEnd = new DateTime(Math.Min(PeriodEnd.Ticks, expirationDate.Ticks)); //Limit period to the min of the two end dates.

        if(PeriodEnd>PeriodStart) //If a valid period
        {
            return new Period()
            {
                StartDate = PeriodStart,
                EndDate = PeriodEnd
            };
        }
        //Default Return Null
        return null;
    }
}
```

I built a console application to test this out:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Discount> Discounts = new List<Discount>();

    Discount d1 = new Discount(new DateTime(2014, 3, 1), new DateTime(2015, 02, 28));
    Discount d2 = new Discount(new DateTime(2014, 7, 1), new DateTime(2015, 06, 30));
    Discount d3 = new Discount(new DateTime(2014, 01, 1), new DateTime(2015, 12, 31));

    Discounts.Add(d1);
    Discounts.Add(d2);
    Discounts.Add(d3);

    foreach (Discount d in Discounts)
    {
        d.AddInterval(new DateTime(2014, 4, 1), new DateTime(2014, 11, 30));

        Console.WriteLine("IssueDate:{0} ExpirationDate:{1}", d.issueDate, d.expirationDate);
        foreach (Period p in d.GetPeriods())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start:{0} End:{1}", p.StartDate, p.EndDate);
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Here's what that prints out:

[image: Results]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET):

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public void ExtractSubPeriods()
{
  foreach ( ITimePeriod subPeriod in GetSubPeriods(
    new TimeRange( new DateTime( 2014, 4, 1 ), new DateTime( 2015, 2, 28 ) ) ) )
  {
    Console.WriteLine( "SubPeriods 1: {0}", subPeriod );

  foreach ( ITimePeriod subPeriod in GetSubPeriods(
    new TimeRange( new DateTime( 2014, 7, 1 ), new DateTime( 2015, 6, 30 ) ) ) )
  {
    Console.WriteLine( "SubPeriods 2: {0}", subPeriod );
  }

  foreach ( ITimePeriod subPeriod in GetSubPeriods(
    new TimeRange( new DateTime( 2014, 4, 1 ), new DateTime( 2015, 12, 31 ) ) ) )
  {
    Console.WriteLine( "SubPeriods 3: {0}", subPeriod );
  }
} // ExtractSubPeriods

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public ITimePeriodCollection GetSubPeriods( ITimeRange timeRange )
{
  ITimePeriodCollection periods = new TimePeriodCollection();
  periods.Add( timeRange );

  int startYear = periods.Start.Year;
  int endYear = periods.End.Year + 1;
  for ( int year = startYear; year <= endYear; year++ )
  {
    periods.Add( new TimeRange( new DateTime( year, 4, 1 ), new DateTime( year, 12, 1 ) ) );
  }

  TimePeriodIntersector<TimeRange> intersector = new TimePeriodIntersector<TimeRange>();
  return intersector.IntersectPeriods( periods );
} // GetSubPeriods
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things to consider:

- As humans, we typically use fully-inclusive ranges for date-only values, while we use half-open intervals for time-only or date+time values.  *Think: 2 days from Jan 1 to Jan 2, but 1 hour from 1:00 to 2:00, or from Jan 1 Midnight to Jan 2 Midnight.*
- .Net's built-in `DateTime` type, is a date+time type.  When you omit the time, it uses midnight.  You *cannot* remove the time portion.
- If you were to use `DateTime` with date-at-midnight ranges, the best you could do is choose to ignore the time portion.  That makes for some tricky code, as you would have to normalize your inputs to midnight before comparing against the range.  I don't recommend this approach, as it is error prone.  The edge cases will pile up quickly.
- Therefore, I recommend either switching to half-open intervals with `DateTime`, or if you need to continue to use fully-inclusive ranges then consider using the `LocalDate` type from [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org).  I will show you examples of both.
- Because you are accepting month numbers as inputs, consider that you should also handle the case of them being out of sequence.  That is, a two-month sub-period may range from December of one year, to January of the next.
- Unless there are guarantees that the outer period will fall *exactly* at the start and end points of a whole month, you will need to trim the results.  For example, if your Period ran from Jan 3 2014 to March 9 2016, then the subperiod in 2015 would have the whole months, but 2014 would be trimmed at the start and 2016 would be trimmed at the end.

Here is how you can achieve this using `DateTime` and half-open date-at-midnight intervals:

```
public class DateTimeInterval
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The date and time that the interval starts.
    /// The interval includes this exact value.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime StartDate { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The date and time that the interval is over.
    /// The interval excludes this exact value.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime EndDate { get; private set; }

    public DateTimeInterval(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        StartDate = startDate;
        EndDate = endDate;
    }

    public IEnumerable<DateTimeInterval> GetSubIntervals(int startingMonth,
                                                         int endingMonth)
    {
        // Determine the possible ranges based on the year of this interval
        // and the months provided
        var ranges = Enumerable.Range(StartDate.Year,
                                      EndDate.Year - StartDate.Year + 1)
            .Select(year => new DateTimeInterval(
                              new DateTime(year, startingMonth, 1),
                              new DateTime(
                                startingMonth > endingMonth ? year + 1 : year,
                                endingMonth, 1)
                                .AddMonths(1)));

        // Get the ranges that are overlapping with this interval
        var results = ranges.Where(p => p.StartDate < this.EndDate &&
                                        p.EndDate > this.StartDate)
                            .ToArray();

        // Trim the edges to constrain the results to this interval
        if (results.Length > 0)
        {
            if (results[0].StartDate < this.StartDate)
            {
                results[0] = new DateTimeInterval(
                    this.StartDate,
                    results[0].EndDate);
            }

            if (results[results.Length - 1].EndDate > this.EndDate)
            {
                results[results.Length - 1] = new DateTimeInterval(
                    results[results.Length - 1].StartDate,
                    this.EndDate);
            }
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

Using the above code:

```
var interval = new DateTimeInterval(new DateTime(2014, 3, 1),  // inclusive
                                    new DateTime(2015, 3, 1)); // exclusive
var subIntervals = interval.GetSubIntervals(4, 11);
```

And here is how you can achieve the same thing using `NodaTime.LocalDate` and fully-inclusive date-only intervals:

```
using NodaTime;

public class LocalDateInterval
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The date that the interval starts.
    /// The interval includes this exact value.
    /// </summary>
    public LocalDate StartDate { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The date that the interval ends.
    /// The interval includes this exact value.
    /// </summary>
    public LocalDate EndDate { get; private set; }

    public LocalDateInterval(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate)
    {
        StartDate = startDate;
        EndDate = endDate;
    }

    public IEnumerable<LocalDateInterval> GetSubIntervals(int startingMonth,
                                                          int endingMonth)
    {
        // Determine the possible ranges based on the year of this interval
        // and the months provided
        var ranges = Enumerable.Range(StartDate.Year,
                                      EndDate.Year - StartDate.Year + 1)
            .Select(year => new LocalDateInterval(
                              new LocalDate(year, startingMonth, 1),
                              new LocalDate(
                                startingMonth > endingMonth ? year + 1 : year,
                                endingMonth, 1)
                                .PlusMonths(1).PlusDays(-1)));

        // Get the ranges that are overlapping with this interval
        var results = ranges.Where(p => p.StartDate <= this.EndDate &&
                                        p.EndDate >= this.StartDate)
                            .ToArray();

        // Trim the edges to constrain the results to this interval
        if (results.Length > 0)
        {
            if (results[0].StartDate < this.StartDate)
            {
                results[0] = new LocalDateInterval(
                    this.StartDate,
                    results[0].EndDate);
            }

            if (results[results.Length - 1].EndDate > this.EndDate)
            {
                results[results.Length - 1] = new LocalDateInterval(
                    results[results.Length - 1].StartDate,
                    this.EndDate);
            }
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

Using the above code:

```
var interval = new LocalDateInterval(new LocalDate(2014, 3, 1),   // inclusive
                                     new LocalDate(2015, 2, 28)); // inclusive
var subIntervals = interval.GetSubIntervals(4, 11);
```

Answer (score 0):

This shoud work:

```
var periods = Periods
    .Select(p => new {
            p = p,
            a = p.StartingDate.Year*12 + p.StartingDate.Month - 1,
            b = p.EndingDate.Year*12 + p.EndingDate.Month
        }
    )
    .Select(x => new {
        period = x.p,
        subperiods =
            Enumerable
            .Range(x.a, x.b - x.a)
            .Select(e => new DateTime(e/12, e%12 + 1, 1))
            .Where(d => StartingMonth <= d.Month && d.Month <= EndingMonth)
            .GroupBy(i => i.Year)
            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
            .Select(g => new Period {
                StartingDate = g.Min(),
                EndingDate = g.Max()
            })
            .Select(p => new Period {
                StartingDate = p.StartingDate < x.p.StartingDate ? x.p.StartingDate : p.StartingDate,
                EndingDate = (p.EndingDate > x.p.EndingDate ? x.p.EndingDate : p.EndingDate)
                    .AddMonths(1)
                    .AddDays(-1)
            })
        });
```

[image: results]

**UPDATE**

According to your image, this would do the trick:

```
var periods = Periods
.Select(p => new {
        p = p,
        a = p.StartingDate.Year*12 + p.StartingDate.Month - 1,
        b = p.EndingDate.Year*12 + p.EndingDate.Month
    }
)
.Select(x => new {
    period = x.p,
    subperiods =
        Enumerable
        .Range(x.a, x.b - x.a)
        .Select(e => new DateTime(e/12, e%12 + 1, 1))
        .Where(d => StartingMonth <= d.Month && d.Month <= EndingMonth)
        .GroupBy(i => i.Year)
        .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
        .Select(g => g.Select(i => i))
    });
```

[image]